# BASH JQ command

Tags: json, linux, iteration, jq

Suppose I have the following json in the file ver.json:

```
[{"id":"123","product":13038},{"id":"456","product":1212}]
```

Why when I apply the "jq" command I get this result?

```
jq -r '(.[].id|tostring) + "," + (.[].product|tostring)' ver.json

123,13038
456,13038
123,1212
456,1212
```

This would be the correct answer:

```
123,13038
456,1212
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little messy. Because you are piping twice and concatenating you are ending up with a cartesian product.

Instead pipe `.[]` once to two different parentheticals:

```
~$ jq -r '.[] | (.id | tostring) + "," + (.product | tostring)' ver.json
123,13038
456,1212
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Or more compactly:

```
$ jq -r '.[] | "\(.id),\(.product)"'
123,13038
456,1212
```

It may also be worth noting that `@csv` retains the types:

```
$ jq -r '.[] | [.id,.product] | @csv'
"123",13038
"456",1212
```